# Quartz.Net - How to associate an object to an IJobDetail

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I'm using quartz.net in my project and i want to associate an object with the IJobDetail.

I know there is an option of using

> UsingJobData

but I can put there only strings, ints and such, but I want to put there an object, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the answer after trying few things my self, its kinda wired that its not in their documentation, but whatever.

This is how it goes:

```
IDictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
data.Add("Data#1", MyData1);
data.Add("Data#2", MyData2);

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().SetJobData(new JobDataMap(data));
```

And in the execute method in the job we will receive it like this:

```
var data1 = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Get("Data#1");
```